# Is this calculus proof correct?

Tags: integration, proof-verification

Let
$$ f(x) = \int^{x}_{-2} (x + 2) g(t) \, dt.$$
The domain of $g$ and $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Assuming $g$ is a positive continuous function, show $f(x) \ge  {0}\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My proof is:

Since $g$ is a continuous function, it is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. So $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists\ c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\int ^{x}_{-2} (x + 2) g(t) \, dt = (x + 2) \int ^{x}_{-2} g(t) \, dt = (x+2) \cdot g(c) \cdot (x - (-2)) = (x+2)^2 g(c).$$ 
Since $g$ is a positive function, $g(c)$ is positive. Since $(x+2)^2$ is a non-negative function, their product is always $0$ or bigger.

Comment: It’s problematic to use that $(x+2)g(x)$ is a continuous function because in the original problem, $g$ is a function of $t$ not $x$. Note that you can pull the $(x+2)$ out of the integral since this expression is not dependent on the variable of integration $t$, so it acts like a constant.

Comment: @layman right, that makes sense and is definitely a mistake. Going to correct that part, but it won't have an influence in the latter part, will it?

Comment: Maybe the intended question was $f(x)=\int^x_{-2}(t+2)g(t)\,dt$?

Comment: @zipirovich it's not!